# alamofireobjectmapper requestObject cant make correct request and mapping

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, objectmapper

Hi I'm having an issue with parsing.

When I try to parse [this](https://api.vid.me/channel/1/new) JSON in my tableviewcell
and can't get the values ​​that I need.

My request:

```
    let videos = NewestVideos()
    let URL = "https://api.vid.me/channel/1/new"


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        Alamofire.request(.GET, self.URL).responseObject { (response: Response<NewestVideos, NSError>) in

            switch response.result {
            case .Success(self.videos):
                print("")
            case .Failure(let error):
                    print("Request failed with error: \(error)")

            }
        }
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NewTableViewCell

        cell.newVideoNameLabel.text = resultr


        return cell
    }
```

How do I get values in tableviewcell, and make the correct request?

My mapping via ObjectMapper:

```
    class Videos: Mappable {
    var embedUrl: String?
    var title: String?

    required init?(_ map: Map){

    }
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        embedUrl <- map["embed_url"]
        title <- map["title"]

    }
}

class NewestVideos: Mappable {
    var videos: [Videos]? = []


    required init?(_ map: Map){

    }
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        videos <- map["videos"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mappable classes look okay, apart from Videos should be Video.

```
class Video: Mappable {

    var embedUrl: String?
    var title: String?

    required init?(_ map: Map) {}

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        embedUrl <- map["embed_url"]
        title <- map["title"]
    }
}

class NewestVideos: Mappable {

    var videos: [Video]? = []

    required init?(_ map: Map) {}

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        videos <- map["videos"]
    }
}
```

Next in your controller, you were doing something weird with your switch statement. You should be letting the response result as `.Some` and then setting `self.videos` to the `newest.videos`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, ... {

    ...

    var videos = [Video]() {
        didSet {
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    ...

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        let request = Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://api.vid.me/channel/1/new")

        request.responseObject { (response: Response<NewestVideos, NSError>) in

            switch response.result {
            case .Success(let newest):
                self.videos = newest.videos
            case .Failure(let error):
                print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }

    ...

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NewTableViewCell
        let video = self.videos[indexPath.row]

        cell.newVideoNameLabel.text = video.name

        return cell
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: oh thnk u its must work but i have one more question where i must make reloadData() to see changes

Comment: i dnt undetstand my app crash i think tabbarcontroller with tableviewcontroller?

Comment: when i try reloaddata